# Virtualbox installation problem

Tags: linux-mint, apt, virtualbox

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgsoap-2.8.60 libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms
Suggested packages:
  vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Recommended packages:
  virtualbox-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgsoap-2.8.60 libvncserver1 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 345 kB/18,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86,9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libgsoap-2.8.60 amd64 2.8.60-2build1 [222 kB]
Get:2 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libvncserver1 amd64 0.9.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 [122 kB]
Fetched 345 kB in 0s (879 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap-2.8.60:amd64.
(Reading database ... 326863 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgsoap-2.8.60_2.8.60-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgsoap-2.8.60:amd64 (2.8.60-2build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvncserver1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libvncserver1_0.9.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.34 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-88-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-88-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/updates/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/updates/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/updates/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/updates/

depmod........

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up libgsoap-2.8.60:amd64 (2.8.60-2build1) ...
Setting up virtualbox (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
vboxweb.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.39) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: Your installation did not "go well" if you're getting these errors. How did you install VB 6.1?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/571722/4778

Comment: I haven't any errors reports trough installation process.

Comment: I edited the previously message..

Comment: OK, so you successfully installed VB 5.2.34 - is this what you wanted? You should probably install **virtualbox-qt**; kinda surprised it wasn't in the main install.

Comment: It's  working after installation **virtualbox-qt** !  Thank you **ajgringo619** !